# Display or GPU crashed. How to navigate to Device Manager on Windows

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, amd-catalyst

I have an HP G32-301TX with an AMD Mobility Radeon 5470 GPU. Long story short, the GPU doesn't like to be in High-Performance mode very much, it would BSOD and after I forced it shut down (with the power button), the display would never turn on again until I send it for repair. It eventually got to a point where I find that I'm going to waste more money repairing it, so I kept it to using Window's generic display driver instead of the AMD CCC driver. There it would be completely fine. However, after a recent Windows update, I discovered that I was using the AMD CCC driver again, I was trying to change it to Windows Generic Display Driver from Device manager when it BSODed. When I went into BIOS the next boot, it also crashed. Then it went into the black screen again. No boot logo (like an HP logo) and definitely no way for me to know what is going on. I know that it is probably linked to the GPU overheating.

I find that I am still able to boot into Windows (at least I think so, the hard drive seems to be running, the LEDs are normal, CAPS lock is fine (I think).

My question is, how do I go into Windows and navigate to Device Manager and change the driver? How can I be sure that I did not just boot into Startup repair and not Windows?

If I use narrator from Accessibility, can I change the driver using this way? How should I go about turning the narrator on?

Comment: How you conformed that you logged into Windows? If you are not able to see bios also then the problem will be in hardware, So nothing will happen if you change the driver also.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions below to boot into safe mode where you should gain control to replace the driver. Safe mode uses less demanding drivers on most components.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10

Comment: links may go down, rendering your answer completely useless. You'd probably be better off adding the necessary information here. Looks like only one of these options would work here - using a USB key.

Comment: I see, does that mean that I can change the driver through the installation image disk?

Comment: Try safe mode first - It may work - If not then perhaps borrow or buy a USB3 to VGA adapter. There are no other choices when the video on any laptop goes badly wrong.